# Access property of object based on value of another object

Tags: javascript

Below are two objects:

`let x = {y: 'z'}`
and `let a = {z: 'b'}`

I want to access **a.{property}**, where property is the the **value** of **x.y**

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation if you want to use property dynamically

Use `a[x.y]`. Please find example below:

```js
let x = {y: 'z'};
let a = {z: 'b'};

console.log(x.y)
console.log(a[x.y]); // Final result
```

Please use [this link to study about accessing object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)